# How to view code for all subs in a module at the same time

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason my VBA editor changed behavior and now to see the code of another subroutine in a module I have to use navigate to them using dropdowns and thus can see only one at a time.

How do I change the view to see all subs and functions at the same time, only divided by a horizontal line, as it was before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the left hand side of the horizontal scrollbar in VB Editor, there are two button options:

1) Procedure view

2) Full module view.

Select the latter. Hover your mouse to see which is which.

Comment: Using Access since '98 and didn't know that.   Never had need to click those icons I guess and never accidentally clicked them either. :)

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook Same here. I only found out when I accidentally pressed the procedure view one day.